# MathJax not rendering some equations properly on Github pages

Tags: latex, github-pages, mathjax

I've configured Mathjax on my Github pages site and it can render some equations properly but not others.

It can render properly the following equations:

```
\\[ \frac{1}{n^{2}} \\]

\\[ J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^n\theta^2_j] \\]
```

But it can't render equations like below:

```
\\[ F'(\theta_*)=\lim\limits_{\theta\to\theta_*}\frac{F(\theta)-F(\theta_*)}{\theta-\theta_*} \\]
```

Can someone please see where the problem might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to post or link to some HTML output but usually this is due to markdown converting the underscores into `<em>` tags which in turn makes MathJax skip an equation (cf. [the MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents)).

Kramdown (used on GitHub-pages) has special support for $$ to delimit both inline and block equations, which will prevent this kind of interaction, cf. [the kramdown docs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks))

Comment: Thanks Peter. The <em> tags is indeed the problem. I used the $$ sign instead of the "\\[" and "\\]" tags and now it works perfectly.