# How to write matrix with mathjax on github.io markdown?

Tags: latex, github-pages, mathjax

I need write matrix formula on github.io markdown with mathjax. This is my test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//cdn.bootcss.com/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>


formula1:
$$n = x$$

formula2: $$n \neq x$$

formula3:
\(m = y\)

formula4: \[m \neq y\]

formula5:
\\(k = z\\)

formula6: \\[ k \neq z\\]

formula7:
\\[
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 8 & 1 \\
3 & 7 & x \\
6 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\\]

formula8:
\\[
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 8 & 1 \\\\
3 & 7 & x \\\\
6 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\\]
```

this is what markdown shows:

[image]

please tell me how to write a matrix on github.io with mathjax ?

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463849/mathjax-not-rendering-some-equations-properly-on-github-pages/ (or pick another one of the many "mardkown is messing up TeX code" postings.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MathJax not rendering some equations properly on Github pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463849/mathjax-not-rendering-some-equations-properly-on-github-pages)

Comment: linrongbin, did you get it figured out?

Comment: @Nathan, this question is long time ago, I cannot remember all the details. Please see my github repo as a tutorial: https://github.com/linrongbin16/way-to-algorithm